# How to make plants uneatable for cattles

Tags: plant-care, pest-control, pesticide

Is there any spray or powder that we can spread on top of the leaves of plants.

So that Either cows or goats won't consume that.

There are insecticide or pesticide or so many cides which makes plant impervious to insects and other disease causing bacteria or protozova or virus.

But I couldn't find any such thing for cattles.

Please note building a fence or wall is not an option for me.

Update:

I don't want any liquid or powder to kill cattles but if these liquid or powder make animal skip those plants then that'd be great

Comment: What kind of plants? What part of the world?

Comment: As a rule, killing cattle or goats that eat your plants is considered socially unacceptable in most areas, (that's what a "-cide" does.) Depending on the customs or rules of your local area you may be able to seek reparations for crop damage from the owner of the animal for not keeping them fenced in, or you may be expected to provide a fence to keep them out, whether or not you consider that an option.

Comment: @kevinskio - These are decoration plants , South Asia

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Sorry, I've updated my question.

Comment: I expect it is the same for deer ; You can not stop them long term

Comment: Bordeaux mixture?

Comment: It's usually used for fungus right ? Can it also be used for cattles ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a non-toxic [spray repellant such as Liquid Fence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TS4WBUQ).
Made specifically for spraying the home garden against deer and rabbits, the concoction is not a poison at all. It is a stinky garlic and rotten egg smell that disappears to humans, but lasts a month for grazers.

You may need to change clothes after application, as opposed to going directly to a job interview or on a date. Use it directly on the leaves and your harvest, too. (Wash it off later!)

Comes in a pre-mixed spritz bottle or a concentrate. Worth a try or blend your own.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions

- We have used chilli powder in the past to stop dogs from defecating in our yard, but it may not be practical.
- We have used mesh wire cages to stop birds from pulling the plants out, we have a native bird that likes doing it.
- And there is electric fence. You can get small solar units. We are using it now to stop cows from eating our plants. Visually there are white pigtail stakes and a white ribbon berween them.

Comment: Electric fence with solar unit is interesting.